# PHP/MySQL Data manipulation or query to get sum of values in this result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
array (
    0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'name' => ' Richard ',
     'invoice_number' => '000002',
    'invoice_due_date' => '07/24/2015',
     'client' => '7',
     'filename' => 'INV-1436536128.pdf',
     'paid' => '0',
     'sent' => '0',
     'pending' => '1',
     'actioned_by' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'created' => '1436535725',
     'reseller' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'description' => 'fgsdf',
     'id' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'rates' => '4',
     'quantity' => '3',
     'price' => '12',
     'company_name' => 'Fabric',
     'email_address' => 'richardgregson1989@gmail.com',
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'name' => ' Richard ',
     'invoice_number' => '000002',
     'invoice_due_date' => '07/24/2015',
     'client' => '7',
     'filename' => 'INV-1436536128.pdf',
     'paid' => '0',
     'sent' => '0',
     'pending' => '1',
     'actioned_by' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'created' => '1436535725',
     'reseller' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'description' => 'asdfasdf',
     'id' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'rates' => '8',
     'quantity' => '3333',
     'price' => '26664',
     'company_name' => 'Fabric',
     'email_address' => 'richardgregson1989@gmail.com',
  )),
  2 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'name' => ' Richard ',
     'invoice_number' => '000003',
     'invoice_due_date' => '07/24/2015',
     'client' => '7',
     'filename' => 'INV-1436538414.pdf',
     'paid' => '0',
     'sent' => '0',
     'pending' => '1',
     'actioned_by' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'created' => '1436538404',
     'reseller' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'description' => 'dsfasdfas',
     'id' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'rates' => '2',
     'quantity' => '2',
     'price' => '4',
     'company_name' => 'Fabric',
     'email_address' => 'richardgregson1989@gmail.com',
  )),
  3 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'name' => ' Richard ',
     'invoice_number' => '000003',
     'invoice_due_date' => '07/24/2015',
     'client' => '7',
     'filename' => 'INV-1436538414.pdf',
     'paid' => '0',
     'sent' => '0',
     'pending' => '1',
     'actioned_by' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'created' => '1436538404',
     'reseller' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'description' => 'sdfgsdfg',
     'id' => 'a5576d1e307279-24a803be-e2b4935fd38dfdc3ed028eb0128ccab6',
     'rates' => '2',
     'quantity' => '2',
     'price' => '4',
     'company_name' => 'Fabric',
     'email_address' => 'richardgregson1989@gmail.com',
  )),
)
```

Now in this array I want to get the total of all fields named price and output them as a total where the invoice numbers are the same...

So my question is, what would be best.. Can I do this using GROUP_BY and SUM in my query.. Or would I be best looping through the array and calculating the sum of price using a foreach loop?

Also could you give me an example of how either of these options would look? As I tried a few loops and cant seem to quite get the hang of adding them toegther only when the invoice numbers match.

Oh and here is my query so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", d.title, d.firstname, d.lastname) as name, b.*, a.description, a.id, a.rates, 
        a.quantity, a.price, c.name as company_name, c.contact_email as email_address
        FROM invoice_management_invoices_items a
        RIGHT JOIN invoice_management_invoices b ON b.invoice_number = a.invoice_number
        LEFT JOIN config_clients as c ON b.client = c.id
        LEFT JOIN users_details d ON b.actioned_by = d.id
        WHERE a.id = :i
        AND b.pending =1
        AND b.sent = 0
```

Regards

Comment: is that php dump a representation of your mysql table setup/contents?

Comment: Not quite that's the dump from the query result